# How do use where condition to new created column for count used group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
SELECT tail_number, sum(passenger_count) as total_passenger 
from flights 
group by tail_number 
where total_passenger > 600
```

How can get total_passenger is more than 600 using where in this SQL query.

Comment: Change WHERE to HAVING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having Clause is used for filtering data using Aggregation function.

Correction in your query:

```
SELECT tail_number, sum(passenger_count) as total_passenger 
from flights 
group by tail_number 
HAVING sum(passenger_count) > 600
```